# JqueryMobile 1.2 - Popups Bug -- Issue with form input on Andorid 4.0 Devices

Tags: android, forms, jquery-mobile, popup

I am testing the new JQM 1.2 popups functionality and noticed an issue when embedding form inputs within the popup.  When browsing to the test site using my Android 4.0 phone, the form inputs within the popup will not bring up the keyboard to allow text input.  Actually the keyboard will pop up, but only for about 1 second and then it will slide away.

This can be replicated by browsing to the following URL using any Android 4.0 device and clicking the "form" example, then attempting to enter text into the log in box:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Does anyone know of any work arounds to force the android keyboard to stay in place to allow user input?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this issue has been reported on the JQM github issue tracker, so it's a known bug.  No fixes yet, but here is the link to check for updates if you're struggling with this issue:  https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4797